# Grep -r "string" doesn't work

Tags: shell, grep

I'am using putty to search for a specific word in a file on my host
.
But when I use: `grep -r "string here"`, the command line just enters, but don't return me anything.

Can anyone tell me how?

I want to search in ALL FILES of the host.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to the directory where you want to search and run the following:

```
grep -r <search string> *
```

That should work.

Comment: And do I have to use the <search string> or without < > :)

Answer (score 1):

looks like you forgot to add directory `grep -r "string here" <directory/files>`

Comment: Hmm, okay but how to search in the whole public_html? just: grep -r "string" public_html?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a recursive search on a directory

This is what you want to do.

```
grep -r <search string> ./
```

Why the grep was stuck because it was waiting for an input stream which you didn't provide the command so it switches to STDIN and whatever you'll type on the terminal it will search on that string